# How to disable Camera from tilting when following a game object?

Tags: unity, physics, camera, rigidbody

I have a game character object which is followed by camera. Camera is child object of Character.

[image]

Using rigid body makes the character tilt in slopes and camera tilts too.

how do i stop camera tilting when character tilts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I have a camera follow my object in Unity?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86375/how-do-i-have-a-camera-follow-my-object-in-unity)

Comment: @Jon no it isn't duplicate. My problem is clearly written in the question.

Comment: I disagree.  Your answer is definitely in that link, the top voted answer.

Comment: Couldn't find the exact thing i want. Please direct me.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/86376/10728

Comment: @Jon untill i set the zOffset to -4 ,the camera doesn't show anything. And please tell me how to modify the code so that camera stops tilting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34559/discussion-between-jon-and-user75648).

Comment: @Jon While that link provides an answer, the answer you link to is not the answer to this question. It is not a duplicate. That answer specifically says make the camera a child. While this might work for some game types, it is actually what is causing the problem in this scenario.

Comment: @dval I tried to explain it to him in the chat, the link is right above your comment if you wanted to read what I had written.

Comment: @Jon, thanks! I updated the answer to include your solution. I wouldn't have thought of doing it that.

Comment: Actually, making a camera a child of an object gives the game engine a chance to optimize some things. I'm not at all saying unity is this good, but there is no good reason to avoid making the camera a child in a well designed system. EDIT: To be clear, there *is* possible benefit from it. Blindly avoiding it is *bad* advice. The type of thing people repeat to each other without understand what they are talking about.

Comment: @MickLH of an object?  any object or does it have to be the one that is rotating specifically? would the OP recieve the same unnamed benifits if the camera was child of any other game object other than his character? what is the *possible* benifits of making camera a child of the player, vs. an empty gameobject?

Comment: @dval Hierarchical scene graph information is exploited in countless ways, it's an art form of its own... You will have to read some literature for a glimpse of how huge the answer is to that *seemingly innocuous* question really is. If you need an example and can't be bothered to learn on your own, consider being able to coalesce culling operations for entities which need to consider nearby entities (Like maybe, a player, and a camera?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your second sentence.

> Camera is child object of Character.

The Camera should not be a child of the character. This is what is causing the camera to tilt. A child will follow its parent's transform.

Remove the Camera from the Character.  The script @Jon linked to will do what you want by modifying the camera transform, as the character moves without modifying rotation. So, your Camera shouldn't tilt at all.

If you need the camera to be a child of your character, @Jon offers another solution in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34559/discussion-between-jon-and-user75648) he links to that updates the Camera with an inverse rotation of your character.

Comment: Or, you can simply set the LocalRotation to 0, or whatever the initial value was.

Comment: If the local rotation is zero, and it's linked to a spinning parent, it will still spin. Did you mean global rotation?

Comment: No, local rotation of the gameobject, it will use the rotation of the parent object. You can then leave the object as the child if you did this.

Comment: @Jon can you proivide any documentation on this, both [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/146118/rotate-transform-without-rotation-the-children.html) and [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/334925/change-rotation-of-parent-independently-without-af.html) state the opposite. And a google search for 'unity rotate a parent without rotating child?' returns a lot of similar answers suggesting workarounds in reparenting.

Comment: No I can't I just know that I've done this before.   I wouldn't recommend it, as it is basically resetting the child's rotation on each frame.